# Where is the "Visualize code on sequence diagrams" feature in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am looking for the `Generate Sequence Diagram`-command in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, but I can´t find it. Has this feature been removed? Here is a link to the documentation describing the feature in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317485(v=vs.120).aspx